# Where can I post a home-brew classes for peer review in the interest of balance?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, homebrew

I've created a new partial caster class that focuses on using spell slots solely for the purposes of suppressing magic in the world. I'm calling it the Void Mage. I've done my best to make it balanced using the guidelines from [creating new classes](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/creating-new-classes/). I've also had the players I regularly play with contribute to balancing as well.

Now I feel like I should have it reviewed by someone outside of our circle in order to have a more unbiased opinion. Where can I upload my home-brew class so that others may comment and critique my work?

Comment: Yup, totally is. Not sure why I wasn't able to find this when I searched for home brew, etc >.< Thank you for pointing me towards this

Comment: I got a lot of good feedback from the rpg forum on here, I appreciate it very much! I feel much more confident bringing my Home-brew class to the table now